Stretchable Round Div
I'm trying to create a time picker like this [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/ZoshU.png
however I have found it difficult. I have managed to create stretchable div however I'm struggle to round it like a doughnut.
Any help or guidance would be much apricated :)
CodeSandboxLink - https://k2hstz.csb.app/
Code
  const [isDisplayed, setIsDisplayed] = useState(false);
  const [isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown] = useState(false);
  const [divWidth, setDivWidth] = useState(0); // Initial width

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    setIsMouseDown(true);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      setDivWidth(e.clientX);
    }
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsMouseDown(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className='min-w-[250px] w-full relative select-none p-4'>
        <div>
          <div
            id="draggableDiv"
            className='border-2 bg-red-600 p-4 rounded-full'
            style={{ width: `${divWidth}px`  }}
            onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseUp}
          ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App


I would look at existing round/circular sliders such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fseehawer/react-circular-slider or https://marc.khouri.ca/react-circular-slider/
